# Access a property and change its value

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get an access and change `localModel>PROPERTY_VALUE` in my controller. This was implemented before, not by me. So I am stuck here. I know, there is `setProperty()` that I could use, but still don't know how.

```xml
<xx:Repeater items="{
  path: 'localModel>/reportData/',
  filters: {
    path: 'TYPE',
    operator: 'EQ',
    value1: 'CONCLUSION'
  },
  templateShareable: false
}">
  <TextArea value="{localModel>PROPERTY_VALUE}" rows="8" width="100%"/>
</xx:Repeater>
```

controller.js

```js
ReportService.getReportData(oDataModel, caseUuid).then(function (data) {
  that.localModel.setProperty('/reportData/', data);
});
const interpretationTextArea = this.localModel.getProperty('/reportData').find(it => it.PROPERTY_NAME === 'CONCLUSION');
if (interpretationTextArea) {
  interpretationTextArea.PROPERTY_VALUE = 'Bla' + interpretationTextArea.PROPERTY_VALUE;
}
```

Here is how data looks like inside:

[image: Here is how data from getReportData() looks like inside]

Comment: Is the value changed but the UI is not updated? `this.localModel.refresh(true);` might help.

Comment: Cool, that works! If you submit the response as an answer, I will accept it. Actually, calling rerender() can be also an option, isn't? @Marc

Comment: Rerender is protected. You would also create a strong coupling between your model and your UI. Calling refresh is like triggering an event, and every subscriber (e.g. your UI Control which has a binding to your model) will react.

Comment: Also if you actually used `setProperty` you wouldn't even need `refresh`. setProperty will also trigger rerendering. Usage: `model.setProperty("/reportData/0/PROPERTY_NAME", "myNewValue");` Can ofc be made dynamic by replacing the 0 with some `findIndex` stuff

Comment: @Marc thanks for ur response, I have also tried it with a direct access  by setting an index to `/0` which worked. Compared to`this.localModel.refresh(true);` are there pros/cons of using  `model.setProperty()`  instead or they are synonims in this regard?

Comment: I think the main difference for JSONModels is performance. Calling setProperty to update 1000 objects takes a few seconds. If you directly modify the object and then call refresh(true) it's just a few milliseconds.

Comment: @Marc somehow I thought that  `setProperty('propertyX', val)` is also a targeted way and optimized in this regard. Meaning: it won't trigger 1000 objects update..

Comment: I meant that calling setProperty in a loop or `forEach` will call a lot of code in the background. So if you have a scenario where you change many objects at once it's better to update the json object directly and not call `setProperty`